# Energy harvesting in expanding universe?

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, energy, cosmology, space-expansion

There has been much discussion (in Physics Stack Exchange for instance) about how could we (theoretically) extract energy from the accelerated expansion of the universe.

However, the only gedankenexperiment I can found is the "tethered galaxies" one (e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0104349).

However, has somebody proposed an alternative mechanism or can someone come up with an alternarive scenario where we could make useful work from the accelersted universe expansion without using exceedingly speculative elements (like exotic matter)?

Comment: Full text freely available from [researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2229537_Solutions_to_the_tethered_galaxy_problem_in_an_expanding_universe_and_the_observation_of_receding_blueshifted_objects).